# sudo dkms add command issue

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, dkms

I am trying to setup my WIFI adapter settings. I have already run command

```
sudo apt install git build-essential dkms
```

when i try to do this

```
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
```

that shows me following error

**`Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/.-rtlwifi_new does not exist.`**

how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

don't run this command in "rtlwifi_new" directory
so back one directory
cd ..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).